# Why does the posterior region and the right ventricle of the heart are not well represented in standard 12 leads?

Tags: cardiology, electrocardiography

When assessing an ECG we divide our 12-lead into four main contiguous lead groups: inferior, lateral, septal, and anterior. Regions not well represented on a standard 12-lead are the posterior region and the right ventricle, So if there is an infarction in these regions how we can determine it ?[image]

Comment: The answer should have source or reference and not the question and this is known in ECG that lead l , aVL,V5 & V6 looking for lateral region of heart ...ect as shown in photo above.